# How does Storing Failable Results for Later / trailing closure syntax to call Result(catching:) work in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling, closures, storage

Within chapter on error handling there is an example on expression evaluator and code on storing Failable Results for Later - code below, lines after implementation of function evaluate. This part does throw more errors, would like to ask if you can help to clarify these. I am going back from the beggining of the book again, checking sources and practicing more examples. Still appreciate your help, so when comming back can study it more.

```
enum Token: CustomStringConvertible {
    case number (Int)
    case plus
    
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .number (let n):
            return "Number: \(n)"
        case .plus:
            return "Symbol: +"
        }
    }
}

class Lexer {
    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case invalidCharacter (Character)
    }
    
    let input: String
    var position: String.Index
    
    init(input: String) {
        self.input = input
        self.position = input.startIndex
    }
    
    func peek() -> Character? {
        guard position < input.endIndex else {
            return nil
        }
        return input[position]
    }
    
    func advance() {
        assert(position < input.endIndex, "Cannot advance past endIndex!")
        position = input.index(after: position)
    }
    
    func getNumber() -> Int {
        var value = 0
        
        while let nextCharacter = peek() {
            switch nextCharacter {
            case "0" ... "9":
                let digitValue = Int(String(nextCharacter))!
                value = 10*value + digitValue
                advance()
            default:
                return value
            }
        }
        return value
    }
    
    func lex() throws -> [Token] {
        var tokens = [Token]()
        
        while let nextCharacter = peek() {
            switch nextCharacter {
            case "0" ... "9":
                let value = getNumber()
                tokens.append(.number(value))
            case "+":
                tokens.append(.plus)
                advance()
            case " ":
                advance()
            default:
                throw Lexer.Error.invalidCharacter(nextCharacter)
            }
        }
        return tokens
    }
}

func evaluate(_ input: String) {
    print("Evaluating: \(input)")
    let lexer = Lexer(input: input)
    do {
        let tokens = try lexer.lex()
        print("Lexer output: \(tokens)")
    
        let parser = Parser(tokens: tokens)
        let result = try parser.parse()
        print("Parser output: \(result)")
    } catch Lexer.Error.invalidCharacter(let character) {
        print("Input contained an invalid character: \(character)")
    } catch Parser.Error.unexpectedEndOfInput {
        print("Unexpected end of input during parsing")
    } catch Parser.Error.invalidToken(let token) {
        print("Invalid token during parsing: \(token)")
    } catch {
        print("An error occured: \(error)")
    }
}

class Parser {
    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case unexpectedEndOfInput
        case invalidToken(Token)
    }
    
    let tokens: [Token]
    var position = 0
    
    init(tokens: [Token]) {
        self.tokens = tokens
    }
    
    func getNextToken() -> Token? {
        guard position < tokens.count else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let token = tokens[position]
        position += 1
        return token
    }
    
    func getNumber() throws -> Int {
        guard let token = getNextToken() else {
            throw Parser.Error.unexpectedEndOfInput
        }
        
        switch token {
        case .number(let value):
            return value
        case .plus:
            throw Parser.Error.invalidToken(token)
        }
    }
    
    func parse() throws -> Int {
        var value = try getNumber()
        
        while let token = getNextToken() {
            switch token {
            case .plus:
                let nextNumber = try getNumber()
                value += nextNumber
            case .number:
                throw Parser.Error.invalidToken(token)
            }
        }
        return value
    }
}

evaluate("10 + 1")

// below is code on Storing Failable Results for Later:

let lexer = Lexer(input: "1 + 3 + 3 + 7")
let tokensResult = Result { try lexer.lex() } // Result<Success, Failure>' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

enum Result<Success, Failure> where Failure : Error {
        case .success(Success) // Extraneous '.' in enum 'case' declaration
        case .failure(Failure) // Extraneous '.' in enum 'case' declaration
    }

switch tokensResult {
case let .success(tokens):
    print("Found \(tokens.count) tokens \(tokens)")
case let .failure(error):
    print("Could not lex \(lexer.input): \(error)")
}

let numbersResult: Result<[Int],Error> = tokensResult.map {
      tokens.compactMap { token in // Cannot find 'tokens' in scope
          switch token {
          case let .number(digit): return digit
          default: return nil
          }
      }
}

func extractNumbers(from result: Result<[Int],Error>) throws -> [Int] {
        return try result.get() // Value of type 'Result<[Int], Error>' has no member 'get'
    }
```

Comment: `Result` is a native Swift generic enumeration. Anyway the error is pretty clear should be `case success(Success)`. Btw just remove the whole declaration

Comment: I wonder why would you need to use `Result` on a synchronous method. Anyway you need to change your `lex()` method return type to `Result<[Token], Parser.Error>`

Comment: Thanks Leo for clarification, let lexer = Lexer(input: "1 + 2") , let tokensResult = Result { try lexer.lex() } and print(tokensResult) works. Authors state that the function’s output tucked into a single enum can be passed around in program or stored as a property of an object. One can also process it later using a switch statement. Also state that Result has several features for working with its cases, could use its map(_:) method to transform the success value if there is one. And to either return data or throw error of Result type, they present possibility to use its throwing get() method.

Comment: They say that the Result type is a flexible way to store success/failure states that you need to cache or are not ready to process yet. That many frameworks use Result for passing around the results of background work. Just wanted to know how I can correct the errors that are within code to explain these possibilities.

Comment: @LeoDabus what adjustment should I use in line "return tokens". Now after changing lex() method return type to Result<[Token], Parser.Error> it says: Cannot convert return expression of type '[Token]' to return type 'Result<[Token], Parser.Error>'

Comment: of course you need to return success or failure. `.success(tokens)` or `.failure(.invalidCharacter(nextCharacter))`. Btw your Result Failure type should be `Lexer.Error` instead of `Parser.Error`

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried some changes as per code in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70878204/how-to-use-result-type-to-store-success-failure-states-in-swift if you can help me to check.